# Magento 2 - Order Address Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I created an observer for this event

> sales_order_address_save_before

```
<?php
namespace UV\Adressen\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class LieferadresseEditObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
  private $customerRepository;

  public function __construct()
  {

  }

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    print_r(get_class_methods($observer));
    exit;
  }
}
?>
```

However how can I get the changed address and how can I see if it is a shipping or a billing address? thanks!:-)

Comment: Could you tell us where is this event (sales_order_address_save_before) declared? Is it in your custom module?

Comment: it's built in magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
$address = $observer->getEvent()->getAddress();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using observer for **sales_order_place_before** event

```
<?php
namespace UV\Adressen\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class LieferadresseEditObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    $order->setBillingAddress($order->getShippingAddress());

  }
}
?>
```